# ¿Cómo solucionar error en retorno de datos mysql, hay límite?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

Buen día tengo un problema con una aplicación web, de la cual obtengo datos de un php ej. `solicitudes.php` tengo 10,000 solicitudes exactamente que se retornan (de una bd mysql) en un arreglo de este tipo (abajo especificado). El problema es que al entrar directo al archivo php no me traes los registros, probando con un `limit` me trae los registros hasta un limite menor de 9868 registros, es decir al poner limit 9569 me da

> internal server error 500

Nota: solo me pasa en servidor de producción, en local funciona al 100%,
memory limit y time response del servidor ya los ajuste, descartados errores en consulta, ya que trae todo bien (menos cuando supera el limite mencionado), versiones de php y mysql son las mismas que en local donde funciona, no se si tendré que configurar algo en el servidor, agradezco su ayuda.

```
$json[] = array(
        "folio"=>$res->folio,
        "idsolicitud"=>$res->idsolicitud,    
    );
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Sería interesante que mostrases el código con el que obtienes los datos. 10,000 registros no es tanto, quizá el código necesite ser optimizado, ¿qué usas, PDO, MySQLi? El hecho de construir tú mismo el array da la impresión de que en efecto tu código no está optimizado, pues PDO y MySQLi tienen métodos para eso. ¿La BD tiene bien indexadas las tablas? Un simple `SELECT * ` puede ser problemático... Como ves, a la pregunta le faltan datos. Si fuera tú no le echaría tan rápido la culpa al servidor, la culpa puede ser de un código o de un diseño mejorables.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, por alguna razón el problema resulto ser el array(o la memoria asiganda al mismo)

```
 $json[] = array(
            "folio"=>$res->folio,
            "idsolicitud"=>$res->idsolicitud,  
             "otrocampo"=>$res->otro,
             "otromas"=>$res->otromas, 
              (etc.. aquí retornaba varios elementos unos 13 aprox)
        );
    }

echo json_encode($json);
```

La solucion se dio al quitar los elementos que regresa el array es decir quedo algo como:

```
 $json[] = array(
            "folio"=>$res->folio,
           (Regreso solo 1 elemento)

        );
    }

echo json_encode($json);
```

es decir retornando solo un elemento(en realidad de 13 retorne 10 y fuciono), lo que me hace pensar si supere el limite de elementos del array o la memoria o algo por el estilo...